# Arel::Nodes::Grouping - How to phrase Nested selects in query rewritten from SQL string

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a Rails query that incorporates a query on an HABTM join table `projects_posts`.

```rb
class User < AbstractModel
  has_many: :posts
  has_many: :projects_created, class_name: "Project"

class Post < AbstractModel
  belongs_to: :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many: :projects

class Project < AbstractModel
  belongs_to: :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many: :posts
```

Here's the query in SQL, that I have successfully rewritten in Arel:

```sql
SELECT posts.* FROM posts, projects_posts
WHERE ( posts.user_id = #{user_id} )
OR ( projects_posts.project_id IN ( #{project_ids} )
    AND projects_posts.post_id = posts.id )
```

This originally suggested an `Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin` solution, and the join works fine.

```rb
posts = Post.arel_table
pjp = Arel::Table.new(:projects_posts)

constraints = posts.create_on(posts[:id].eq(pjp[:post_id]))
join = posts.create_join(pjp, constraints, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)

results = Post.joins(join).where(
  posts[:user_id].eq(id).or(pjp[:project_id].in(project_ids))
).uniq.sort
```

#### Goal

I'd like to try to write it as a nested Arel query without the left outer join. I'm aiming to write Arel that generates something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts 
  WHERE ( posts.user_id = #{user_id} )
  OR id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT( post_id ) FROM projects_posts
            WHERE project_id IN ( #{project_ids} ) )
```

I want to do this because I believe the nested SELECT may be faster at a larger db scale. (Please correct me if that's a wrong impression).

I've been reading up on `Arel::Nodes::Grouping` in nested queries, and I'm close, but i don't entirely understand how to use that with `IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ...)`. I've got the following so far, but I am not confident how to put them together to return ActiveRecord results.

```rb
inner_select = pjp.project(pjp[:post_id]).
               where(pjp[:project_id].in(project_ids)).uniq
post_ids_array = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(inner_select)
outer_select = posts.project(Arel.star).where(posts[:user_id].eq(id).
               or(posts[:id].in(post_ids_array)))
results = Post.find_by_sql(outer_select.to_sql)
```

That generates the following SQL, which seems close enough.

```sql
  SELECT * FROM posts 
  WHERE ( posts.user_id = #{user_id} ) 
  OR ( posts.id IN (
   ( ( SELECT projects_posts.post_id 
       FROM projects_posts 
       WHERE projects_posts.project_id IN ( #{project_ids} ) 
  ) ) ) )
```

So, two questions.

1. How can i return ActiveRecord results (of `Post` objects) without `find_by_sql`?
2. Am I using `Arel::Nodes::Grouping` correctly? The `post_ids_array` does return the correct IDs.

Comment: I think you are over thinking this. An OUTER JOIN will function perfectly fine and possibly better from a planning standpoint (although I am not a DBA). Also the Grouping is completely unnecessary in the second implementation because IN is already wrapped in parens.

Comment: Also whatever `project_ids` is would likely be better executed as a sub query as well.

Comment: Understood - just removed the grouping. (At one point, when i was passing `inner_select` to `outer_select` directly, my query had thrown an error, and that sent me searching for `grouping`. But now i understand it was unrelated to the grouping). Agree about the maybe-overthinking. It was the DBA, who requested my method not use an OUTER JOIN! But your comment induced me to research further, i'm not sure there would be much difference. `project_ids` is produced by its own method, but i believe you're right about that. Will try nesting it.